# Is there an exact solution to the minimum distance from a $\tan(x)$ curve to the origin?

Tags: calculus

Of course, there is the trivial answer that the minimum distance is 0, since tan passes through the origin, but what I'm interested in is the solution when $x < -\frac{\pi}{2}$, ie. this point here:
[tan x graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G64pV.png)

My first instinct is to minimise $\sqrt{x^2 + \tan^2 x}$ by differentiating and setting to 0. However that yields $\tan x \sec^2 x = -x$ which I'm unable to solve explicitly. Is it possible to do so? Or do I have to be content with numerical approximations?

Comment: Do you mean like $x < -\frac \pi 2$?

Comment: You have to numerically approximate the solution.

Comment: Yeah, sorry I mean $x<-\frac{\pi}{2}$

Comment: Amazing, isn't it ? Thanks for the problem; I had a lot of fun with it ! Cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An exact solution, no but a good approximation is possible.

Plotting the function $f(x)=x^2+\tan^2(x)$, you noticed that its minimum is around $-\frac{3 \pi }{4}$. So, consider 
$$f'(x)=2 \left(x+ \tan (x) \sec ^2(x)\right)$$ and expand it as a Taylor series built at $x=-\frac{3 \pi }{4}$. Forget the factor $2$ and this would give
$$x+ \tan (x) \sec ^2(x)=\left(2-\frac{3 \pi }{4}\right)+9 \left(x+\frac{3 \pi }{4}\right)+20
   \left(x+\frac{3 \pi }{4}\right)^2+O\left(\left(x+\frac{3 \pi
   }{4}\right)^3\right)$$ Solve the quadratic equation and keep the solution which is the closest to the reference point. This would give for the minimum
$$x_{min}=-\frac{3 \pi }{4}-\frac{9}{40}+\frac{\sqrt{960 \pi -1264}}{160} \approx -2.31959 $$ Use this value to get
$$f(x_{min}) \approx 6.53833$$

Using numerical methods, you should find $x_{min}\approx -2.31981$ and $f(x_{min}) \approx 6.53833$ (!!!). This does not seem to be too bad.

**Edit**

More amazing : instead of Taylor series, use the simplest $[1,1]$ Padé approximant. This will give
$$x+ \tan (x) \sec ^2(x)=\frac{\frac{1}{9} (41+15 \pi ) \left(x+\frac{3 \pi }{4}\right)+\frac{1}{4} (8-3 \pi
   )}{1-\frac{20}{9} \left(x+\frac{3 \pi }{4}\right)}$$ The numerator cancels at $$x_{min}=-\frac{72+96 \pi +45 \pi ^2}{164+60 \pi }\approx -2.31982$$

To get a nice looking result for the distance, we can also build the $[2,2]$ Padé approximant for $f(x)$. This would be
$$x^2+\tan^2(x)=\frac{\frac{\left(865+936 \pi +360 \pi ^2\right) \left(x+\frac{3 \pi
   }{4}\right)^2}{3 (83+60 \pi )}-\frac{3 \left(-152-13 \pi +99 \pi ^2+36 \pi
   ^3\right) \left(x+\frac{3 \pi }{4}\right)}{2 (83+60 \pi )}+\frac{1}{16}
   \left(16+9 \pi ^2\right)}{-\frac{128 \left(x+\frac{3 \pi }{4}\right)^2}{3 (83+60
   \pi )}-\frac{8 (13+12 \pi ) \left(x+\frac{3 \pi }{4}\right)}{83+60 \pi }+1}$$ which, computed for the last derived $x_{min}$ would give for the square of the minimum distance
$$d_{min}^2=\frac{1034864+3537936 \pi +4479480 \pi ^2+2456622 \pi ^3+673353 \pi ^4+34020 \pi
   ^5}{16 \left(202451+283464 \pi +79353 \pi ^2+3780 \pi ^3\right)}$$ which is again $\approx 6.53833$

**Update**

Being lazy, we can  solve the problem (with a  loss accuracy) expanding $f(x)$ as a Taylor series around $x=-\frac{3 \pi }{4}$. This will give
$$f(x)=\left(1+\frac{9 \pi ^2}{16}\right)+\left(4-\frac{3 \pi }{2}\right) \left(x+\frac{3
   \pi }{4}\right)+9 \left(x+\frac{3 \pi }{4}\right)^2+O\left(\left(x+\frac{3 \pi
   }{4}\right)^3\right)\tag 1$$
$$f'(x)=\left(4-\frac{3 \pi }{2}\right)+18 \left(x+\frac{3 \pi
   }{4}\right)+O\left(\left(x+\frac{3 \pi }{4}\right)^2\right)\tag 2$$ This makes
$$x_{min}=-\frac{2}{9} (1+3 \pi )\approx -2.31662$$ and using $(1)$
$$f(x_{min})=\frac{1}{18} \left(10+6 \pi +9 \pi ^2\right) \approx 6.53756$$